# What file have I to create in my custom WordPress theme to show all the post belonging to a specific category?

Tags: php, posts, theme-development, loop, customization

I am pretty new in WordPress theme development and I have the following doubt.

I am working on this custom theme: http://lnx.asper-eritrea.com/

Into this website upper horizontal main menu I have a link named **LEGACY-POSTS** (the last one) that should show the list of all the posts belonging to a specific category (named **legacy-posts**).

Clicking on this link I obtain a white empty page: lnx.asper-eritrea.com/category/legacy-posts/

I think that it could depend by the fact that maybe I have to implement this page. Is it right?

I was looking on the **Template Hierarchy** official WordPress documentation page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

But I am finding some difficulties to understand what name I have to use for the file that implement this page.

Can you help me?

Tnx

Comment: Do you have archive.php or category.php in your theme which is empty?

Comment: yes, these 2 files are empty

Comment: it seems you have archive.php in the theme which is empty.Am i correct?

Comment: category.php file is used to render posts belonging to specific category.since it is empty ..you are getting a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom template for one specific category should be named `category-slug.php` where "slug" is the WP slug for the category.  WordPress will automatically use this file to display the archive for that one category.

You could also name it using the ID of the category.

If your category is "legacy-posts", then your template file should be named `category-legacy-posts.php`.